# Multiple instances of web browser control using different proxies

Tags: .net, proxy, browser, webbrowser-control, instance

I need to run 2 or more instances of my program (which is a simple webbrowser control with some extra features), and on each instance I need the webbrowser control to use a different proxy to connect to the internet.

Last time I used IE web browser control was on C++ and I remember having to edit the registry to set the proxy, but that caused the normal IE to use the proxy too, and there was no way to use multiple instances with different proxies.

Does someone have a solution for this?

I could use C++, C# O VB.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannnot set the proxy per insnance. Not even per application - it is global. If you change it for a .net app, it will impact IE as well.

Perhaps you could create multiple 'virtual machines' and set a different proxy for each one?

If you dont want to do that, perhaps you can can change the proxy, navigate, change the proxy again, navigate again... you would have to write some code that decides how the applications will 'take turns'

Changing the proxy settings will impact .NET apps on the fly - you do not have to restart the application, or even the webbrowser control, for the changes to take place.

Here is complete code to change the proxy.

Create a "Form1" with buttons "B_Get" "B_Set" and "B_Disable" and then paste this code.

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices



Public Class Form1

    <DllImport("wininet.dll")>
    Public Shared Function InternetSetOption(hInternet As IntPtr, dwOption As Integer, lpBuffer As IntPtr, dwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    Public Const INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED As Integer = 39
    Public Const INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH As Integer = 37


    'This function is what is called after editing the registry - this causes internet explorer to update its proxy even if it is already open.
    'It also effects the web browser control in any VB.net application that is running.
    Public Sub globalProxy_apply()
        Dim settingsReturn As Boolean = False
        Dim refreshReturn As Boolean = False
        settingsReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0)
        If Not settingsReturn Then
            MessageBox.Show("Error 001: Line ""InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, IntPtr.Zero, 0)"" failed.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
        refreshReturn = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0)
        If Not refreshReturn Then
            MessageBox.Show("Error 002: Line ""InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH, IntPtr.Zero, 0)"" failed.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function globalProxy_IsProxyEnabled() As Boolean
        Try
            Dim Regs As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree)
            If Regs.GetValue("ProxyEnable") <> Nothing Then
                If Regs.GetValue("ProxyEnable").ToString() = "0" Then
                    Return False
                Else
                    Return True
                End If
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error 01X: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function globalProxy_GetProxyServer() As String
        Try
            Dim Regs As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree)
            If Regs.GetValue("ProxyServer") <> Nothing Then
                Return Regs.GetValue("ProxyServer").ToString()
            Else
                Return ""
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error 02X: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Return ""
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Sub globalProxy_DisableProxy()
        Dim regkey As RegistryKey
        Try
            regkey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings")
            regkey.SetValue("ProxyEnable", False, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
            regkey.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error 03X: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try

        globalProxy_apply()
    End Sub

    Public Sub globalProxy_SetProxy(ByVal ServerName As String)
        Dim regkey As RegistryKey
        Try
            regkey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings")
            regkey.SetValue("ProxyServer", ServerName, RegistryValueKind.Unknown)
            regkey.SetValue("ProxyEnable", True, RegistryValueKind.DWord)
            regkey.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error 04X: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try

        globalProxy_apply()
    End Sub

    Private Sub B_Set_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles B_Set.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            globalProxy_DisableProxy()
        Else
            globalProxy_SetProxy(TextBox1.Text)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub B_Disable_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles B_Disable.Click
        globalProxy_DisableProxy()
    End Sub

    Private Sub B_Get_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles B_Get.Click
        If globalProxy_IsProxyEnabled() Then
            TextBox1.Text = globalProxy_GetProxyServer()
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```